# If state rework, ignore-case clarification

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, ignore-case

So, I have a class that creates a Song object containing a Title: Artist: Album.
I prompt the user to ask for a particular artist, and from an ArrayList containing a master play list, the program returns a list, sorted by Title, for each particular artist.  This was no problem.  The issue I am having is at the point where the user asks for an artist that is not in the master play list.  When I code this using an if/then/else, I am receiving one Sysout for every case in which the prompted artist does not match an artist in the master play list.  Also, when the user inputs a proper artist, the correct, formatted Arraylist is generated, along with the Sysout for every artist that didn't match the prompted name (so, the entire master list essentially).  I need to EITHER return a formatted ArrayList containing only the artist prompted, or a single statement, such as, "Artist not found in list."  I've been stuck for a couple of hours, and need a couple of fresh minds on this, if you will.  I know why it is happening, I just can't figure my way around my intended output.  Also, a little help in understanding why ignoreCase() is not working for me (for checking the searchArtist against an instance variable of Song object) would a big help.

Below is the current code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;


public class SongList {


  public static void main(String[] args){


  //An arraylist theList to accept a file containg title : artist : album
    ArrayList<Song> theList = new ArrayList<Song>();


  try{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    File inputFile;
   // Prompts user for proper input
      do{ System.out.println("Please enter a valid input file.");
          String input = in.next();
          inputFile = new File(input);
     }while(!inputFile.exists());


    Scanner inp = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFile));

   String line = ""; 
   //Accepts a line that is greater in length that 2 (it assumes a colon, and one blank space)
   while((inp.hasNextLine()))
   {
     line = inp.nextLine();
     line = line.trim();
     if(line.length() > 2){
       Song n = createSong(line);
       theList.add(n);
     }
   }
  }

   catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error with the input file: " + e.getMessage());
   }

   Collections.sort(theList); //Sorts by title

   //An arrayList particularArtist that creates an arrayList of a specified artist as given by the     user
   ArrayList<Song> particularArtist = new ArrayList<Song>(); 
   Scanner sa = new Scanner(System.in);
   String searchArtist = "";

   System.out.print("Please enter the name of an artist you'd like to find.");
   searchArtist = sa.next();
//This is where I am having the issue.
    for(Song theArtist : theList)
      if(theArtist.getArtist().contains(searchArtist))
    {
      particularArtist.add(theArtist);
    }
    else{System.out.println("The artist you are looking for does not exist in the play list.");}

    for(Song is : particularArtist)
    System.out.println(is);


  }
   /*
    * Method for creating a Song object given an input file. In the format "Title : Artist: Album,"     substrings
    * are created at the colons, and white space is trimmed.
    */

   public static Song createSong(String a) {
    int index1 = a.indexOf(':');
    int index2 = a.indexOf(':', index1 + 1);
    Song s = new Song(a.substring(0, index1).trim(), a.substring(index1 + 1, index2).trim(),     a.substring(index2 + 1).trim());
    return s;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution:** if the match exists then add to the result list (particularArtist). If the result list is empty then print artist doesn't exist.

```
for(Song theArtist : theList) {    
  if(theArtist.getArtist().contains(searchArtist)) {  
      particularArtist.add(theArtist);  
  }
}  

for(Song is : particularArtist) {
  System.out.println(is);
}

if (particularArtist.size() == 0) {
  System.out.println("The artist you are looking for does not exist in the play list.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I was staring at my code for so long that I passed over this simple concept.  The output was as intended.  Again, thank you.